# How many posts are returned on Instagram's new hashtag endpoint (documentation does not specify)?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Now that Instagram has changed their API, I am not sure how many posts are returned on the hashtag endpoint. Is it all of them? Or should the maximum be specified as a parameter? Does anyone with an accepted application who uses this API endpoint have any more info they could share?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get around 24 posts per API call with Graph API, and the posts limited to last 7 days